# How to create a dynamique data base

Tags: asp.net-core

i'm working with .Net core, i want to create a data base of a stock so that the user can add a new type of product with unknown features and he can also add features to existing product.
i really need help with the design of the data base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases have *schemas*. This is a rigid structure that defines both the characteristics and constraints of the data that can be placed in it. You cannot do something like dynamically add columns, etc. without fundamentally impacting the database integrity.

In true relational databases (SQL Server, MySQL, Postgresql, etc.). Such changes are flat out disallowed. However, some less rigid NoSQL solutions are either schema-less or have malleable schemas and will allow you to just start tracking some new data point without first altering the structure of the database. Even then, though, data integrity becomes a serious issue, and you can end up borking your entire dataset if you do this kind of stuff willy-nilly.

Long and short, there's really no "dynamic" where databases are concerned. Even in NoSQL solutions, you're largely expected to plan out your data structure before hand, and failure to do so, results in inconsistencies in the data that can negate its usefulness entirely.

Your best bet for something like the described requirement is to actually have a `Features` table. In the simplest form, it might just have a string column for a name and a foreign key or simply an ID referencing column (depending on whether it's relational or not) back to the product it's associate with. You'll need a primary key as well, which could either be a composite of the name and product ID (essentially making the combination a unique) or you might want to have an actual identity type column.

The key with data, in general, is to generalize. Nothing is completely unique and is just usually variations of other things. Boil down your data to least common denominators to determine your actual schema. Then, where there's outliers, you can take a less-rigid strategy like described above.